# Creating a line layer that links many points in layer to one point in another layer?

Tags: qgis, postgis

Let's say there's point layer A with 300 points and point layer B with one point

How to create a line layer that connects all points in layer A to the one point in layer B?

Using QGIS and/or PostGIS.

Comment: try using the st_makeline function

Comment: @ziggy was trying to do just that but the documentation isn't very clear and there's no example with geometries from different tables

Comment: ive never used this function but I would imagine it would be something like this: select t1.columns etc,t2.columns etc.. st_makeline(t1.geom,t2.geom) from t1,t2

Comment: @ziggy getting syntax error on the brackets when I tried  select 
 id,
  geom as st_makeline(a.geom, b.geom),

Comment: post your whole query

Comment: @ziggy  select 
 id,
  geom as st_makeline(a.geom, b.geom),
  exchange,
  postcodes 
From test.pipe a, test.exc b

Comment: st_makeline(a.geom, b.geom) as geom

Comment: @ziggy ERROR:  Input geometries must be points or lines. I'm a 100% sure that both layers are points

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In QGIS, you can use the **Connect Points** plugin which you can download from:

```
Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins...
```

---

Example:

1. Here are a couple of layers, `layer_A` has a bunch of points; `layer_B` has one. Make sure both layers contain an integer field where the values are exactly the same (e.g. both my layers have an `id` field where all values are `1`). The plugin uses this to connect your points. When your plugin is enabled, go to its settings:

   [image: Interface]

---

2. Select the options:

   [image: Settings]

---

3. Result:

   [image: Result]

---

Note that this plugin is experimental so you will need to enable the `Show also experimental plugins` option (thanks to [@blue_chip](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/28942/blue-chip)):

```
Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins > Settings
```

Comment: Not sure why my edit was deleted but anyway in case you haven't read it: wow guys some pretty varied answers here. One Python, one plugin and one Postgis. Giving the tick to the plugin one as it's the most GIS noob friendly and also because of the smiley face. Thanks all!

Comment: @Luffydude - Your edit was probably deleted because it didn't add much to your overall question but you're right, very different answers! :)

Comment: You need to enable experimental plugins to find this one. I had to look a bit longer until it dawned on me.
Plugins > Setting > Check _Show also experimental plugins_

Comment: @blue_chip - Apologies, I should have mentioned that. Will edit that in :)

Answer (score 3):

if both of your layers are points this below query should work just plug in your own data. I did a test with creating lines from 1 layer with 150+ point rows and a layer with 1 point

```
drop table if exists line;
create table line as
select layer1.id ,st_makeline(layer1.geom,point.geom) as geom from layer1,point
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Assuming to start from this situation (one point layer with one feature and one point layer with 300 features):

[image]

you may run this code from the **Python Console** (after having loaded the two layers of interest in QGIS):

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant

layer1 = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('1point')[0]
crs = layer1.crs().toWkt()
layer2 = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('300points')[0]

outLayer = QgsVectorLayer('Linestring?crs='+ crs, 'line_output' , 'memory')
prov = outLayer.dataProvider()
fields = layer1.pendingFields()
for field in layer2.pendingFields():
    fields.append(field)
prov.addAttributes(fields)
outLayer.updateFields()

for feature in layer1.getFeatures():
    coords = feature.geometry().asPoint()
    attr1 = feature.attributes()

    for feat in layer2.getFeatures():
        seg_start = coords
        seg_end = feat.geometry().asPoint()
        attr2 = feat.attributes()
        attrs = attr1 + attr2
        outGeom = QgsFeature()
        outGeom.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([seg_start, seg_end]))
        outGeom.setAttributes(attrs)
        prov.addFeatures([outGeom])

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(outLayer)
```

for obtaining this result:

[image]

You only need to adapt the names for the layers (`'1point'` and `'300points'`) to the names with which they are loaded in the **Layers Panel**.

My approach will work **independently** from the number of features in both layers.